# Gratis Windows software to check hard drive

Tags: windows, gratis, hard-disk, hardware

Please recommend gratis Windows software to check every sector on a hard drive.

I just want *read* verification for each sector; I don't need *write* verification.

Can be a GUI app, or run from the command line.

I'm considering just using `chkdsk`, but I'm wondering if there are better tools that I should consider because they feature *any* of the following (none are requirements):

- Improved speed
- A visual map of any bad sectors/clusters
- Ability to pause and resume the test

Answer (score 2):

I like [Ariolic Disk Scanner](https://www.ariolic.com/disk-scanner/); it is free and provides read verification with a visual map of the disk showing any bad clusters. It doesn't do repairs, but that was not part of your requirements. You can see this and some other free disk scanners [here](https://www.technize.net/5-free-tools-to-check-hard-disk-for-errors-chkdsk-alternatives/).

Comment: Thanks.  It's a nice tool.  Plus, it's portable.  Note that download is thru CNET, which is a bummer, but not the end of the world.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Yeah, I don't like CNet either, but the Ariolic Disk Scanner is a good tool.